# Wrapping C++ and CUDA in Python

Tags: numpy, cython, ctags, mex

I want to create an interface for a numerical library consisting of both OOP C++ (boost) 
and CUDA C code, in Python. There is already an existing MATLAB interface, but it contains 
a lot of mex.h dependencies.

How can this be done as painless as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of links to look at. Could people who've used any of these please comment ?

```
# day  status  packagename  version  homepage  summary

2011-02-03  4  "scikits.cuda"  0.03  http://github.com/lebedov/scikits.cuda/
    Python interface to GPU-powered libraries

2010-10-27  0  "KappaCUDA"  1.5.0  http://psilambda.com
    Module to give easy access to NVIDIA CUDA from Python using the Kappa Library.

2010-10-16  5  "pycuda"  0.94.2  http://mathema.tician.de/software/pycuda
    Python wrapper for Nvidia CUDA

2010-07-01  4  "PyGouda"  1.0  http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycuda
    The EasyCheese of GPU programming
```

Comment: I've used pycuda and would recommend it for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I am using scikits.cuda. but  you need to install [CULA](http://www.culatools.com) full edition for full functionality. It is free for student.